# Magento 2 : check backward compatibility of modules (M 2.4.2 to 2.4.3)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I have upgraded Magento **2.4.2** to **2.4.3**,
I have modules which are customization of core methods.

how can i make sure they are compatible with new magento 2.4.3 version ?

which things i need to check ?

**for example "parent class methods" etc ?**

need advice on it.

Comment: One way is to test those modules again and if they are working fine, you're good to go.

Comment: Retest everything. They pulled a ton of stuff from composer.json. Working on a 2.4.3 upgrade myself.